# Why do bosons tend to occupy the same state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bosons, quantum-statistics

It is often said that, while many fermions cannot occupy the same state, bosons have the tendency to do that. Sometimes this is expressed figuratively by saying, for example, that "bosons are sociable" or that "bosons want to stay as close as possible".

I understand that the symmetry of the wavefunction *allows* many bosons to be in the same one-particle state, but I can't see why they should prefer to do that rather than occupying different states.

Anyway, according to many science writers, bosons not only *can* be in the same state, but they also *tend* to do that. Why is it like that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Suppose you have two distinguishable coins that can either come up heads or tails. Then there are four equally likely possibilities,
$$\text{HH}, \text{HT}, \text{TH}, \text{TT}.$$
There is a 50% chance for the two coins to have the same result.

If the coins were fermions and "heads/tails" were quantum modes, the $\text{HH}$ and $\text{TT}$ states wouldn't be allowed, so there is a 0% chance for the two coins to have the same result.

If the coins were bosons, then all states are allowed. But there's a twist: bosons are identical particles. The states $\text{HT}$ and $\text{TH}$ are precisely the same state, namely the one with one particle in each of the two modes. So there are three possibilities, 
$$\text{two heads}, \text{two tails}, \text{one each}$$
and hence in the microcanonical ensemble (where each distinct quantum state is equally probable) there is a $2/3$ chance of double occupancy, not $1/2$. That's what people mean when they say bosons "clump up", though it's not really a consequence of bosonic statistics, just a consequence of the particles being identical. Whenever a system of bosonic particles is in thermal equilibrium, there exist fewer states with the bosons apart than you would naively expect, if you treated them as distinguishable particles, so you are more likely to see them together.

Comment: I see our answers looked at the question on different sides. You neglected energy levels (H and T could have different energies) dealing with a microcanonical ensemble. On the contrary I focused on the ground state leaving aside statistical aspects - i.e. explaining why there is a tendency towards
ground state.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, there's a thing that troubles me: your argument works for two bosons that can choose between two states, but let's say that our two bosons can choose among k states. Then there will be k cases in which they occupy the same state, and k(k-1)/2 cases in which they don't. If k>3, these last cases are more than the others.

Comment: @HicHaecHoc Yes, but compare this to the naive non-identical particle reasoning: in that case there are $k$ states where they are the same, but $k(k-1)$ when they aren't. For the bosons, this latter number is cut in half.

Comment: @HicHaecHoc The statement is not that any two bosons are more than 50% likely to be in the same state, it's that you get more clumping with bosons than with distinguishable particles when you average over all states.

Comment: @knzhou Thank you! Now I think I understand. So, two bosons actually don't need to have a high probability of being in the same state. They just have more probability of being so (roughly the double in our example) than they would if they were distinguishable.

Comment: Nevertheless, now I think that the common statements as "bosons want to stay close" and the like are a little bit misleading without some explanation.

Comment: @HicHaecHoc "misleading" as most simplified statements like that in science are.

Comment: @HicHaecHoc Popularization is always like that. I think virtual particles are even more misleading, but when my well-intentioned little sister (with zero physics background) wants to know what I'm studying, you better bet I'm weaving a fantastic tale of how virtual particles crash into each other.

Comment: @Aethenosity and knzhou Yes, you are right. I said that just because those statements led me to think that usually bosons have a high probability of sharing one state, but now you made me realize that this needs not to be the case.

Comment: In coming up with the 2/3 value you make a logical leap in assuming equiprobability of events. It's sort of along the same lines as "Either Bill Gates will give me a million dollars tonight or he won't. Therefore, there's a 50% chance I'll be a millionaire tomorrow!" Now, in this particular case equiprobability of the three states may be correct (versus "one each" being twice as likely as either of the others), but the answer could be improved by more directly addressing it, rather treating it in a fashion which normally would be a probabilistic fallacy.

Comment: @R.M. I said "in the microcanonical ensemble", which is precisely the assumption that the states are equally likely. (This is what happens when you give the system a fixed energy and let it come to thermal equilibrium.) But yeah, it's true I didn't justify _why_ that happens -- it's kind of the fundamental postulate that makes all of our reasoning about thermal physics work, so it would be a whole book to say anything more! You could phrase it other ways, but I preferred talking about a thermodynamic example because it makes it easier to connect to the probabilities I had above.

Comment: Is it possible to manipulate the bosons to be in a specific state? Like all in the "one each" state?

Comment: @undefined Sure it is!

Comment: Just to nitpick notice that the states TH and HT are **not** the same, they are different elements in the (tensor product) Hilbert space. Indistinguishable means that, on those two (different) states, there is no observable whose value can be used to distinguish them.

Comment: @gented No, the Hilbert space is 3-dimensional and not 4-dimensional. It's the symmetrized tensor product, not the ordinary tensor product. "Indistinguishable" has a deeper meaning than just being indistinguishable in practice.

Comment: Can you please show an explicit construction of those states in whichever space you are using? Symmetrised Hilbert space does not mean that the two states are the same in that representation, nor does indistinguishable mean that either.

Comment: @gented Let $V$ be a 2D Hilbert space with basis $|0 \rangle$, $|1 \rangle$. The symmetrized tensor product $V \otimes_s V$ is defined to be the Hilbert space with basis $|00 \rangle$, $|11 \rangle$, and $|01 \rangle + |10 \rangle$. Conventionally, we can speak of the states $|01 \rangle$ or $|10 \rangle$ separately, e.g. in a nonrelativistic QM class, but these both refer to the single state $|01 \rangle + |10 \rangle$, c.f. the symmetrization postulate.

Comment: @knzhou So in your notation what you call HT (or TH, respectively) is basically $|HT\rangle \pm |TH\rangle$ (where you take the sign according to the simmetry) :-). The physical state is of course the symmetrised part but my remark was exactly that the two (non-physical) states $|HT\rangle, |TH\rangle$ are still distinct elements in the Hilbert space.

Comment: @gented Sure, that makes sense to me! Indeed, I did a bit of a quick swap when passing to the bosonic case.

Answer (score 9):

> Anyway, according to many science writers, bosons not only can be in the same state, but they also tend to do that. Why is it like that?

That's simply wrong. It's one of many clichés dear to popular science writers but with little physical content. What's true, as you said, is that bosons *can* occupy the same state, as opposed to fermions. As to tendency, it has the same half-truth as when one says "a system tends
to stay in its ground state".

In fact assume the latter statement is inconditionally true and you have an ensemble of *non-interacting* bosons. Then each boson will tend to occupy its ground state and - since nothing forbids that - all particles will sit there. In presence of interaction things may go different or not depending on the interaction.

But the real issue is if there is the tendency of a system to stay in its ground state or go into it if initially placed in a state of higher energy. However this is a question not easy to deal with in few words.

Comment: No, bosons do actually 'clump' relative to classical Maxwell-Boltzmann particles, at least under some circumstances. A nice example is the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect